# Compiler error passing this pointer to a constructor?

Tags: java, scope, jframe, this, jdialog

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    JButton botonCreate = new JButton("Open son windows");

    public void doSomething(){
        botonCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog vce = new JDialog(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the idea is to block the JFrame parent while the child is visible (JDialog).

the parameter of the constructor of the JDialog must be the containing class "MyWindow" but a problem of scope, is the ActionListener, and this generates the following error.

how I can fix this?

error message:

> no suitable constructor found for JDialog()
>       constructor JDialog(java.awt.Frame) is not applicable
>         (actual argument  cannot be converted to java.awt.Frame by method invocation conversion)
>       constructor JDialog(java.awt.Dialog) is not applicable
>         (actual argument  cannot be converted to java.awt.Dialog by method invocation
>   conversion)

Comment: Note that it's generally a really bad idea to extend `JFrame` - you're hardly creating a new kind of JFrame, but instead want to *use* the existing JFrame. The right pattern here is composition not inheritance - that would also avoid the problem altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is simple. When you're using `this` you're actually using `ActionListener.this`. So to correct this error you must explain to the compiler you want to actually use the inclosing class `this` by specifying it with `MyWindow.this`.

```
class MyWindow extends JFrame { 

    JButton botonCreate = new JButton("Open son windows"); 

    public void doSomething(){ 
        botonCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                JDialog vce = new JDialog(MyWindow.this); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to replace this line:

```
JDialog vce = new JDialog(this);
```

to this one:

```
JDialog vce = new JDialog(MyWindow.this);
```

The issue here is that `this`, in the context of the anonymous inner class you're defining, refers to the inner class rather than the `MyWindow` object in which the inner class is defined.  Changing `this` to `MyWindow.this` tells Java that it's the current `MyWindow` object you want, rather than the inner class.

Hope this helps!